# Information gets lost on refresh page - AngualrJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-services

Hi Fellow Genius Developer,

I am learning Angularjs using GitHub API, i successfully get the information on the first call but as soon as i refresh the page all the information is lost and services does not know what to do.

Below is the code of my services please guide me

```
(function() {
    var gitHubApiFactory = function($http) {

        var urlBase = "https://api.github.com";
        var factory = {doneUserName:''};


        factory.getUserName = function(userName) {
            return $http.get(urlBase + "/users/" + userName);
            //doneUserName = userName ;
        };
        factory.getUserRepo = function(userName) {
            return $http.get(urlBase + "/users/" + userName + "/repos");
        };
        factory.getRepoLang = function(userName,repoName) {
            return $http.get(urlBase + "/repos/" + userName + "/" +repoName);
        };
        return factory;
    };

    gitHubApiFactory.$inject = ['$http'];

    angular.module('gitHubApp').factory('gitHubApiFactory',gitHubApiFactory);

}());
```

Please help me on how to fix this problem. So if i refresh the page, services knows what to look for

Thank you all for your time

Comment: Do you have a question or just stating?

Comment: well on page refresh if all information is stored in just memory (javascript objects) they wont persist on a full page reloaded. If you want information to persist against a page refresh you will need to use some storage like localStorage or Cookies

Comment: I have a question, sorry if i did not make it clear in the question. I would like to know how to fix this problem. So all information would be retrieved on page refresh. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use `$cookies`,

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies

if you can, avoid page reload/refresh?

Comment: Thanks, but i guess as mentioned by @Patrick localstorage, i think is a good option.